# WCF .net TCP service fails to start when extra properties are set

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a current project that runs fine with a self-hosted net.tcp binding if I use the following

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMonitorService), new NetTcpBinding() {PortSharingEnabled = false  }, "");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
```

However, if I amend to the below it fails to run with the message that there is already an endpoint on the port, can anyone explain why adding the extra properties causes it to fail?

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMonitorService), new NetTcpBinding() {PortSharingEnabled = false,ListenBacklog=1000,ReceiveTimeout=new TimeSpan(0,3,0)  }, "");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
```

Edit:

Testing confirms that the ReceiveTimeout property works Ok, as soon as I add the MaxConnections or ListenBacklog the service fails to start

Edit 2:

This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/praburaj/2012/10/16/nettcpbinding-mextcpbinding-sharing-same-port-throws-addressalreadyinuseexception-on-upgrade-to-net-4-5/) seems to imply I need port sharing if I want to modify these properties, not sure I am understanding it.

Comment: added a link that looks relevant